# Tensorflow installed but not found when using Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have Tensorflow installed however when trying to import into my jupyter notebook i get this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnlrD.png)

Normally I am assuming that this error occurs when Tensorflow has not been installed.

When I use pip show I can see that it is clearly installed:
[Install shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfidK.png)

Has anyone encountered this issue and knows the solution?

I have tried re-installing but that hasn't solved the issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may not have the correct python kernel running in your notebook, I would advise you to check that the kernel you are running is the one that have tensorflow installed.

Comment: The python kernel was the issue, when switching this solved the problem. Thank you